# Adding pdb files to VSS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

Every time I try to compile my web app, I am prompted if i want to add pdb extensioned files to VSS.

I thought pdb files do not belong in VSS see [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596479/vs2005-and-vss-should-exes-dlls-pdbs-resource-and-generated-xml-files-go).

Is there any way to prevent them from being added.

I cannot even logically delete them from VSS because a previous version has been logically deleted and if I were to delete the current version, the previous version would have to be purged, for which I need vss admin rights that I do not have.

I just can't get a handle on how to avoid getting a million files added to VSS that prevent otehr develoeprs from compiling their solutions because they have unchecked out read only copies. Is the only solution to check them in but flip the readonly flag off locally? This is not a good option in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the containing folder (probably your /bin folder) from the project. That exclusion will be applied to the files within that folder too.

Comment: Your answer sounded reasonable but for class library projects, the bin folder was already excluded. For web apps, I see no way to exclude the bin folder. When I compile, VS tries to add the pdb, dlls and some xml files to VSS. I can't seem to stop it.